# Question to Answer: In INDEX Query, why the SELECT query is much faster than other UPDATE or INSERT query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In INDEX Query, why the SELECT query is much faster than other UPDATE or INSERT query in SQL?

Comment: That are a lot of possible variations.  Please provide specific queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "index query"?

Answer (score 1):

In simplest, select is pulling data already written.  Update and insert have to write the data to the pages and also update indexes, so it needs to traverse all possible indexes of impacted tables.

Additionally, (credit to obe), select queries can take advantage of the cache if the data is associated with a prior query.  It does not need to go back to the original data pages / indexes to re-pull the data.

Comment: Also, in some cases SELECT can benefit from caching, if the same data was requested before.

Comment: Good point.  I will update my answer.  Thanks